# cannot fix this "else" statement error

Tags: python-3.x

the second "else" statement gives a syntax error. I don't understand why. what is wrong with the code? 
Pardon me, still a beginner

```
while True:
guess = input("Guess a letter or the whole word: ")

if guess == word:
    print("Yaye, you've won and have saved my neck!")
    break

else:
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in letters:
            continue
else:
    guesses -= 1
    word_guess(guesses)

if guesses == 0:
    break
```

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? It matters in Python, and is incorrect as posted.

Comment: It looks to me like you swapped the last `if` and `else` blocks with each other at some point in your editing of the code. The `if` needs to be first, though you can of course reverse its condition and put keep the contents of the current `else` block where they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out in another answer, [indentation in python matters](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Is this perhaps the indentation you are looking for?

```
while True:
    guess = input("Guess a letter or the whole word: ")

    if guess == word:
        print("Yaye, you've won and have saved my neck!")
        break
    else:
        for letter in letters:
            if letter in letters:
                continue
            else:
                guesses -= 1
                word_guess(guesses)

            if guesses == 0:
                break
```

Comment: Also it looks like a bug to check `if letter in letters:` inside of the for loop `for letter in letters:`.  Perhaps you means `if letter in word:`?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the Python 3 [flow control documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) an example of an `if` statement. It can only have one `else` statement because that is what is run when all other cases (`if` and `elif`) didn't match. When are you expecting the second else to run?

Comment: Presumably it's supposed to be on the `while`, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: I'm not actually sure. `else` on a `while` doesn't seem like something a beginner would do.